# How to evaluate the line integral $\int_{C}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $A$ and $B$ be the endpoints of the line $C$. Is it possible to express the line integral
$$
\int_{C}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\,dx
$$
using only $f$, $A$ and $B$ (like in the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be well-defined the above integral it must be that case that $C$ is a line with constant $y$, that is, an horizontal line at height $y$. Then for $g(x):=f(x,y)$ you have that $dg=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x)\,d x$, therefore

$$
\int_{C}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x)\,d x=\int_{C}dg=\int_{\partial C}g=g(B)-g(A)
$$

if the endpoints of $C$ are $A$ and $B$ and we understand the integral in $C$ with the orientation from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Thanks but the defintion of a line integral with respect to $x$ is $\int_{C}f(x,y)dx=\int_a^bf(x(t),y(t))x'(t)dt$. Why $y$ is considered to be constant?

Comment: @boaz because you have only the differential form $dx$. If $y$ will not be constant then you will have some form like $dx+dy$ or so

Comment: Is my defintion of line integral with respect to $x$ is worng?

Comment: @boaz your definition is right for this case, and there $y$ must be constant, otherwise we will have a term $y'(t)$ somewhere